# Manipulate DateTime using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Solution table in the database and I want to display any solutions that is less than a day old as of now(DateTime.Now)  Thank you

```
IQueryable<Solution> Solutions=
                        from x in db.Solutions
                        where x.Created_at == DateTime.Now -1
                        select x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) to get target date. Then use `>=` comparison to filter solutions which are less old than target date (or equal to it):

```
IQueryable<Solution> Solutions =
       from s in db.Solutions
       where s.Created_at >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
       select s;
```

NOTE: That will give you entities withing 24 hours from now. If you want to get entities from beginning of yesterday, then use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) instead of [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).